# How to change the startup message when starting webpy server?

Tags: python, web.py

I am using web.py framework to write a commandline tool . I start the server using

```
class MyApplication(web.application):
    def run(self, port=8080, *middleware):
        func = self.wsgifunc(*middleware)
        return web.httpserver.runsimple(func, ('0.0.0.0', port))

app = MyApplication(urls, globals())
app.run(port=9090)
```

When do this I get a console message saying :

```
http://0.0.0.0:9090/
```

How can I override this message to my own custom message ?

Comment: Why? web.py is telling you the host and port it is listening on. That's useful.

Comment: Yes , But in my case I don't want users to see this message . I would like to give a custom message.

Comment: No user will ever see this. It is only displayed on the *server*.

Comment: Clearly, you really want to suppress this message. Why don't you look at the source code of web.py?

Comment: @LutzHorn : I am using webpy in a command line tool , so this message wil l printed on the console when the command is run

Comment: @barny : I am looking into more of a framework level approach to suppress / override the message.

Comment: Wanting that may be admirable but at least in this case you are probably going to be disappointed. Modify httpserver.py.

Comment: A command line tool that starts a HTTP server? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

It's technically possible to override this message by overriding `sys.stdout`

```
import sys
o = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open('/dev/null', 'w')
app.run(port=9090)
```

Surely this will suppress all messages flushed to stdout, so you may need to override/monkey-patch the `WSGIServer.start` method, to assign back the real `sys.stdout` object.

And you can print any custom messages in the override/monkey-patched `WSGIServer.start` function.

fully workable demo:

```
import web
from web import httpserver
import sys


WSGIServer = httpserver.WSGIServer
stdout = sys.stdout
message = "Welcome"


def _WSGIServer(*args):
    server = WSGIServer(*args)
    start = server.start

    def _start(*args):
        sys.stdout = stdout
        print message
        start()
    server.start = _start
    return server
httpserver.WSGIServer = _WSGIServer


class MyApplication(web.application):
    def run(self, port=8080, *middleware):
        func = self.wsgifunc(*middleware)
        return web.httpserver.runsimple(func, ('0.0.0.0', port))


app = MyApplication([], globals())
sys.stdout = open('/dev/null', 'w')
app.run(port=9090)
```